# How to include third party classes into the Android apk?

Tags: android, apk

I have a couple of third party classes which serve as a library I can build my application upon. They are contained in a folder which was added Java Build Path -> Libraries (in Eclipse) with "Add Class Folder". It works fine so far an my app compiles. But the produced .apk contains only my classes and therefore the application does not run.

How can I tell Eclipse to package the third party classes into the .apk as well?

Comment: add them in a jar file? works fine for me

Comment: well ... I had to unzip my third party jar because I have some problems with it.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse will package all 3rd party classes in your apk that are in your Android project's classpath.  It does this by default, as long as you are using the Android SDK plugin for Eclipse.

This is a duplicate of this question (and many others): [How can I use external JARs in an Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project)

Comment: This is perfectly true for jars but with class folders it seems not to work.

Answer (score 2):

Don't need to add anything to Build Path. Just create a sub-folder called "libs" in the project. Put all jar files in libs.