# from where can i get com.sun.cnpi package?

Tags: java, android, package

I m building an android application where I need these packages to import:

```
import com.sun.cnpi.rss.elements.Item;
import com.sun.cnpi.rss.elements.Rss;
import com.sun.cnpi.rss.parser.RssParser;
import com.sun.cnpi.rss.parser.RssParserException;
import com.sun.cnpi.rss.parser.RssParserFactory;
```

What should I do? From where can I find these packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to download [rss_utils_1.1.zip](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javaserverpages/rss_utilities/rss_utils_1.1.zip) as seen in [this tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javaserverpages/rss_utilities/).

Comment: sir, I have a one more problem. m not making a web based application. m making an android application. where should i add this package so that i can use it?

Comment: You will have to include the rss_utils_1_1.jar in your projects `libs/` directory, this answer explains in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694392/importing-external-jar-file-to-android-project/2694903#2694903

Comment: you don't know by accident where to get the source?

Comment: Links are broken. Anyone can give out a new link?