# Java (Android) - class not found exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, installation

I'm trying to do some simple FTP stuff in Android.  After researching a little bit, I decided to go with the [apache-commons-net](http://commons.apache.org/net/).  Here are the steps I took to get it working under Eclipse.

1. Downloaded the package [from here](http://commons.apache.org/net/download_net.cgi) and unpacked it locally.
2. In Eclipse, to add this new library, I go to **(Window >) Preferences > Java > Build Path > User Libraries**, click **New**, name it `apache-commons-net`, then **Add JARs...** to it by picking the *.jar* files that came in the download.
3. For each *.jar*, I add in the **Source attachment** as [described here.](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/10601-how-make-apache-commons-stringutils-etc-work-eclipse.html)
4. Once this is done, I right-click my project and choose **Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries**, click **Add Library... > User Library > (Next >) choose `apache-commons-net` > Finish**.  The library then shows up alongside `Android 2.2` in the **Libraries** tab.

I start programming, and code completion works fine for the classes/methods/etc. from this library.  Import statements are included, etc.  Everything seems to work as it should.  The problem is, when I run the app, it force closes and my LogCat in Eclipse shows the following error:

> Could not find class 'org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient', referenced from method <...>
>   ...
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient

It seems like I've set everything up correctly, so why is the execution complaining that it can't find the class???

Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated.

- Ian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to copy the jar(s) to the `libs` directory in the project. The ADK picks the libraries from that folder and convert them into classes optimized for Dalvik.

#### Edit

There might be some more information in this question: [Importing external .jar file to Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694392/importing-external-jar-file-to-android-project)

Comment: Umm, my project doesn't have a `libs` directory.  Should this have been created when I generated the project???  What level should it be at?

Comment: Create the `libs` directory at the topmost directory of the project (the same where you have the src and res directories).