# How can I import a class from AWT into my Android project?

Tags: java, android, class, import

I want to import the java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D class because it has got the nice collision detection function .intersect(Rectangle)
Can I use that class in my Android project or won't it work because my project is gonna be an android app?

How can I use that class in my project / how can I import that class to eclipse ?(I dont want to import the whole rt.jar file from the java libs folder)

Can I legaly use that class? Has it got a cc license?

Comment: As this is in the awt package, I am guessing "no". I'm not an Andriod expert, but I think it uses it's own graphics libraries that are not compatible with AWT classes

Comment: Have you checked out this thread yet?: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129109/import-java-project-in-android-application

Answer (score 1):

Android has its own graphics libraries (android.graphics).I think it is not possible to import `Ellipse2D` and you have to try android's libraries.Also You can a check [awt-android-compat](http://code.google.com/p/awt-android-compat/) project.