# Android: Unable to include facebook sdk library project

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

I am working with `Android API 17` on `eclipse Indigo`. I have cloned the `faccebook sdk` from `github` and done the facebook library project set up using the source project provided in the fb sdk.

Now I'm trying to include this library project in my android demo project. I have added it under `Project properties->Android->Library` section. Im seeing green color tick mark infront of the added library.
Also, i have added the same in the `Project properties->Java build path->Projects`.

build is successful. but when i try to install on my AVD, im getting the error, `E/AndroidRuntime(748): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.Facebook`

Can anybody plz help me how to fix this issue.

---- EDIT ------
One more thing I have observed is, when i opened Project properties->Android window, the green tick mark is not displaying under Library section, instead I'm seeing red cross mark.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Venkat Papana

Comment: check if these might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694392/importing-external-jar-file-to-android-project

Answer (score 3):

Same thing happen for me also.. try below .. it will work..

A Best way to add External Jars to your Android Project or any Java project is:

Create a folder called `libs` into you project root folder
Copy your Jar files to the `libs` folder
Now right click on the Jar file and then select `Build Path > Add to Build Path`, this will create a folder called `Refrenced Library` into you project, and your are done
By do doing like this, whenever you transfer you project to other Computer, you will not miss your libraries which are being referenced to some space on your Hard drive.

(The facebooksdk.jar can be found at the facebook-sdk directory: `<facebook-sdk>\facebook\bin`)

Answer (score 2):

i know this question is old But I thought that may be it can help someone.

Move the library project and the application on the same drive. Usually this is a bug in Eclipse.

I solved my problem by moving them in same drive on my computer.
You can Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make both project in same dictionary then include it using Project Properties -> Android-> Library.
This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to add this to the library project as this is not the library.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk is the help of the project ad the sample code for the including the project in our code. Just you need to create the app ID for the facebook by registering your api with it.

Hope this will help you in your project.

Comment: hi Arpit, i'm following https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/ and as per this link, we  have to Add reference to the Facebook SDK. But it is not working for me, i'm getting build errors, (Facebook class not found err). So i have added the project in the build path, then im able to resolve all compilation errors. but deployment is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by copying the `com.facebook.android` source code to my project source.