# XML Parsing issue in android

Tags: android, xml

In a Nodelist.item[index].getChildNodes(), i am getting some junk values in between all the nodes like "#text", what could be the reason ? this is causing an error... Could anyone tell me any permanent fix for this.. is this some sort of namespace issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SAXParser instead. it work simply great

http://java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152

Comment: Use of SAX parser would do nothing to skip text segments, so I don't know why you suggest it?

Comment: i never came across such issue though i had parsed enough content xml.

Answer (score 2):

[Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) is a fantastic library for XML parsing, I guarantee it'll make your life a whole load easier :)

Comment: hmmmm... is this available in android ??

Comment: Sure, there's a guide here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project

Answer (score 0):

Try casting to Element the Node:

```
((Element)Nodelist.item[index]).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()
```

This would retrieve a the desired string.

Comment: hmmmm....my problem is getting extra nodes populated in the doc for certain versions of android only...greater than 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that is white space someone uses indentation. It is not junk -- it is content like anything else, from XML parser's point of view.

But aside from this, if your code errors out due to this, your code is buggy. If you only want to access Elements, get just elements, or check type. You really should not assume things that are not necessarily true.