# How to add an android project as a JAR file in another android project

Tags: android

I have an android project containing only login module. I want to integrate this into another android project. I searched and got the answer that make JAR file of login module project or make that as a library project. At login button click i have to call activity of other project. How can i do this? Please provide best solution to do this integration.

Thanks in advance.
Please Help.

Comment: Android team is currently working on this to support export/import library project as a jar file, probably available in r17, check out their official blog [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/changes-to-library-projects-in-android.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some library module you like to reuse, best way would be  to make plain jar project out of it.  You can see example here:

https://github.com/ko5tik/jsonserializer

This project depends on android libraries and one built and put into repository (thisw is in deed on maven central) it can be referenced by your android project. ( either in IDE settings,  or as maven dependency )

You have to be more specific your build environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own jar file from your classes and you can add it in your android project. See link below for more information, it may help you.

[JAR files and Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857694/how-to-use-your-own-created-jar-file-in-another-android-application)