# Using SQL (JDBC) database in Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, jdbc

In an old Java application I have the following code to connect to a SQL database and use it for some queries:

```
private Connection dbConnection = null;
System.setProperty("derby.system.home", "C:\\");
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
String strUrl = "jdbc:derby:BOOKSDB";
dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(strUrl);
Statement stmt = dbConnection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM BOOKS");
```

Is there any chance to use it on Android? The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/package-summary.html) say that it is possible in general, isn't it? But how can one use it?

Or would it be easier to change this part so that it uses SQLite instead? I think this is much work to do because with SQLite, you always have a cursor instead of a ResultSet and so on ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JDBC on android, provided you supply a JDBC driver that will run on Android.  There is a [open source pure-Java jdbc driver](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-jdbc/) that should run on Android (although I haven't tried it myself).  You will have to adapt the JDBC URL to connect to the sqlite db; that way you can use the local android database while making few changes to your data access code.

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up using SQLDroid.