# Mono for Android MySQL connection

Tags: android, mysql

I have just started to get my feet wet on Mono for Android. I have a remote server that has a MySQL database and my question is that is there a way to connect to the database from my android app and perform SQL queries?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to build a webservice that interfaces between your app and your database! You SHOULD NOT attempt to directly connect!

This looks like a good tutorial and explanation of why you can't connect directly: http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/8339-connect-android-mysql-database-tutorial.html

Some other similar StackOverflow questions:

[android connect to mysql database directly using mysql-connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904742/android-connect-to-mysql-database-directly-using-mysql-connector)

Comment: You are way better off doing this via a web service as you don;t want to store MySQL database credentials in a client app and then open your MySQL DB up to global access.

Comment: And what if you were making a database management application?