# ClassNotFoundException when connecting with mysql jdbc connector on android

Tags: java, android, mysql, classnotfoundexception, connector

I found some answers but nothing was useful.

I added mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar to referenced libraries and the following method to my main class activity.

```
private void getServerData(String id, String type) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
{
    Log.i("Database Connection", " requesting data from server");

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();               
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2:3306/db_easy_maintenance", "root", "maintenance");
    Statement stm = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT Name FROM industrial_object");
    String entry;
    while(rs.next())
    {
        entry=rs.getString("Name");
        Log.i("Database Connection", "getting " + entry);
    }

    con.close();

}
```

I start my app and get an java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at java.lang.Class.classForName.

If I don't use try ...catch... then i get this Exception before compiling.

What's wrong?

Comment: Did you also add the mysql connector jar to your classpath?  Not clear what you mean by "added...to references libraries".

Comment: Did you put the jar in `libs`?

Comment: yes, yes. referenced libraries mean "referenced libraries" in eclipse -> package explorer -> myproject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see: http://developer.android.com/search.html#q=dx&t=0
and [Android JDBC not working: ClassNotFoundException on driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221620/android-jdbc-not-working-classnotfoundexception-on-driver/10822580#10822580) - my answer on the bottom gives ridiculously specific instructions, although I am curious how switching to 1.6 was useful.

Comment: mysql-connector-java-5.1.20 was also bad for me

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the library is exported (has `exported="true"` attribute in `.classpath` file). You can also do that in appropriate tab in project settings in Eclipse.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
 <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
 <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
 <classpathentry kind="lib" exported="true" path="lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar"/>
 <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>

Answer (score 0):

It might not work since Android uses a bit different bytecode. Tyr to check whether MySQL JDBC library correctly translated to Dalvik's format. There's a tool named [dex](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/glossary.html) for translating JVM bytecode into Dalvik's one. If JDBC driver consists classes not portable to Android ones or some native code - you can't use it in Android

Answer (score 0):

JDBC is infrequently used on Android, and I certainly would not recommend it.

JDBC is designed for high-bandwidth, low-latency, highly-reliable network connections (e.g., desktop to database server, Web application server to database server). Mobile devices offer little of these, and none of them consistently.

So the alternative that i advice you to use consist on:

**Create a Web service around your database and access that from Android.**

As side benefits, you improve security (vs. leaving your database open), can offload some business logic from the client, can better support other platforms (e.g., Web or Web-based mobile frameworks), etc.

Comment: i know and my former version used this type of connection, but my boss thinks different. we only use a LAN connection and dont want to publish this app.

Comment: @K_Anas : Can you please show code sample of what you have said? I mean creating web service to access mysql db.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, May be you should try with another JavaSDK and another Android Platform.