# Android: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.communicationsexception communications link failure

Tags: android, jdbc

I have the right IP:Port, so I don't know where is the problem, since communicationsexception comes from broken url:port for the mysql database.

```
package com.bbb.aaa;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://uk1.khttp.net:2083/thedatabase"; // uk1.khttp.net == 95.154.195.28
private static final String user = "theusername";
private static final String pass = "thepassword";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    System.out.println("About to try instantiating driver");


TextView tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    System.out.print("success");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    String result = "Database connection success\n";
    System.out.print("success2");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM testingregistration");
    System.out.print("success3");
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

    while(rs.next()) {
        result += rsmd.getColumnName(1) + ": " + rs.getInt(1) + "\n";
        result += rsmd.getColumnName(2) + ": " + rs.getString(2) + "\n";
        result += rsmd.getColumnName(3) + ": " + rs.getString(3) + "\n";
    }
    tv.setText(result);

    tv.setText("Driver instantiated");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    tv.setText(".....Class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found!");
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        tv.setText(e.toString());
    }

}

}

ERROR LOG: The last packet sent successfuly to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not recieved any packets from the server
```

The console reads and prints "success" but then it crashes after that so it doesnt print "success2" meaning the problem is at connection.

I tried searching the internet for this problem but all they said was that your ip:port and database should be correct but for me this seems correct since I can use that url and port with the login and password details to login to the mysql and then from there I click phpMyAdmin and im in the database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure you've got the permission to connect to the Internet in your manifest.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to add the permission. Though I still get the same error and the script bugs after the first "success" is printed out in the console

Comment: Have a look at the suggestions in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12233178/392781.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting to MySQL from Android with JDBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233145/connecting-to-mysql-from-android-with-jdbc)

Answer (score 1):

use **AsyncTask**. your try catch block code write in `doInBackground` method of asynctask. try it.