# Android Studio ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver after adding module

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc

The error I am getting is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` even though I have already added the .jar file by going to `file -> project structure -> import .JAR Package.` What could be the issue here? 
Image of module inside project structure:

[image]

Comment: have you tried this Connecting to MySQL from Android with JDBC:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233145/connecting-to-mysql-from-android-with-jdbc

Comment: Android studio cannot load the JDBC driver to connect to anything, that is my issue. Even though I have added the jar file, it is not working and I am getting a class not found exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting jar file in your `lib directory`, then re-starting tomcat...

problem is `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` it tries to load the driver, but it is not getting it, this is the reason you are getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.`
check that your jarfile should be in class path

Comment: Okay I've removed the module `mysql-connector-java-5.1.37` and I've added the .jar file directly into my libs folder in this path `project -> app -> libs` and now I am getting a new error `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`

Answer (score 0):

I had a TON of trouble with this for some reason. It is mentioned elsewhere that only 3.017 driver works, and since I made such detailed instructions I figured I'd share them. (My initial purpose was to give steps to reproduce error that I could use to ask a question here and elsewhere. No, I can't begin to guess why I had so much trouble now looking back)

To: Get JDBC Driver in Android app

- New Android Project - AndroidJDBCTest, Target Android4.03, minimum
  sdk 8 (Android 2.2), package name “com.test.AndroidJDBCTest”
- Right click on project, new folder “libs”
- Download Mysql JDBC Driver from here and extract it to your
  filesystem.
- Browse to the root directory after extracting and drag and drop the
  jar mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar into /libs in your project
  in project explorer inside Eclipse., using the default “copy” setting
  for the drag and drop.
- Right click on the Eclipse Project, Build Path-Configure Build Path,
  Add JAR under libraries tab - Browse to /AndroidJDBCTest/libs and the
  jar file and click ok

> NOTE: It shows up now under “Referenced Libraries” node (if Eclipse is
>   set to show it)

Add code from here to the end of `onCreate()` - basically
`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();`
Attach Honeycomb device such as Motorola Xoom family Edition and run

Answer (score -1):

Why are you trying to access MySQL DB from Android native? First it might work but it is not recomended. You can do it easily with `PHP` and `JSON` responses.

Check those:

[http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm
http://sampleprogramz.com/android/mysqldb.php

You can also download my project with `HttpURLConnection` since `org.apache` library has been deprecated.