# How to request multiple data from database and insert into array in Android development

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android development and I'm basically developing my first app asides the HelloWorld examples and all. Now what I want to do is get data from a database (MySQL), I'm using PHP for server-side. The kind of data needed to be collected are blog entries where there are titles, post-images and excerpts. How do I get them in an array such that I'll be able to list them in a *ListView*. Actually, I have an idea running in my head which is - get all data and embed them in custom tags using php as in:

```
<item1>
    <post-title>Title of post goes here</post-title>
    <post-image>http://someimagelink.com</post-image>
    <post-excerpt>Some part of the post body</post-excerpt>
</item1>
```

And same goes for item2, item3, item3 etc which is representing the *ListView* rows respectively. Then I'll use a regex to search between each opening and closing tags.
I don't know if this idea is lame, lol  but I know definitely that its tedious. So I was thinking if there were a direct way handle such task as this or if someone could explain a more simpler way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might use [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) to parse the response. It's as simple as writing jQuery/CSS selectors.

Answer (score -1):

That requires a long answer. the short one is: you need to connect to your db using a [mysql connector for java](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). there are plenty of resources and tutorial out there to learn how to use it ([like this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html)). Sorry but a real answer to this question will require a blog post. I just gave you the tools to start. good luck!

Comment: Thanks fam lemme on the tools u gave 

Comment: That does not really work for Android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233145/connecting-to-mysql-from-android-with-jdbc

Comment: @cyroxis explain your downvote please. my answer is correct. it works on Android but it is not recommended. of course a webservice would be better. I was just replying to the question.

Comment: You are suggesting a officially non recommended solution without 1. Qualifying that this is not recommended 2. Stating why you recommend this over recommended solutions.

Comment: @cyroxis not recommended officially by who?