# jdbc connection on android does not have connection.getSchema()

Tags: android, jdbc, connection

jdbc connection on android does not have connection.getSchema(). It was added in Java SE 1.7. Does android fully support java 1.7 jdbc?

Answer (score 1):

JDBC is not properly supported in android. You need to use some web services such as REST APIs.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18181589/5137352) and other answers in that thread for solution.