# I want to make Android application with MySQL

Tags: android, mysql

I want to make Android application with MySQL. But I don't know what to do with it. I'm new to Android development. I want to make an application that draws pictures, titles and articles with MySQL. You might think of it as a WordPress site sharing your article. Reading the data is enough because I can write it manually to phpMyAdmin. For example, you clicked an article with a summary on the homepage and displayed it all.

[My dream app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAJsq.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a database with a connection open to the whole world isn't a really secure way of sharing data with your application. Also you can't really run a jdbc driver on Android. If you want to read more about that [here are some good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233145/connecting-to-mysql-from-android-with-jdbc).

You really need to write an API for your Android application if you want this kind of feature. Or you can just set up a Firebase Database which is a really good option for a small application. It's free up to 1gb and 100 simultaneous connections.