# Record is not added to Sqlserver database using Android and Sqlserver

Tags: android

i am creating the simple crud using android and sqlserver database. when i click add button record is not added in the database.but no errors shown,
code which i tried i attached below.some one help me to solve this problem.i am tring this two days ago.but i couln't

```
 EditText ed1,ed2;
    Button b1,b2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ed1 = findViewById(R.id.title);
        ed2 = findViewById(R.id.course);
        b1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        b2 = findViewById(R.id.v1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                insert();
            }
        });
    }

 public void insert() {
        try {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://KOBINATH-PC; databaseName=skill; user=sa; password=admin123";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            PreparedStatement pst;
            String title = ed1.getText().toString();
            String description = ed2.getText().toString();

            pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into course(coursename,fee)values(?,?)");
            pst.setString(1, title);
            pst.setString(2, description);

            pst.executeUpdate();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            ed1.setText("");
            ed2.setText("");
            ed1.requestFocus();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Record Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what are value you are passing while insert query?

Comment: java, javaaaa     ......................

Comment: is there any mistake in the code sir.

Comment: You have to give specific ip instead of PC's name in connection url. for more information regarding code check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18181589/5370550

Comment: Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.8.101/skill", "sa", "admin123"); i tried the code but record not added sir

Comment: it should be live ip not a local ip, to work with real devices

Comment: Sqlserver database how to get the ip address sir

Comment: check this article https://amberpos.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/215978723-How-to-find-your-database-IP-address-and-SQL-port

Comment: it is not working for me sir

Comment: You can use emulator for local ip address

Comment: is there any way to modify the code sir simply connect sqlserver and andrid studio

Comment: is the device which you are running your app on connected to the same local network as your server?

Comment: yes sir. emulator Genmotion i am using can you write code

Comment: `192.168.8.101` is wrong IP to connect to the host PC in genymotion. try `10.0.2.2` or `10.0.3.2`

Comment: i tried but not working sir.  String connectionUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.0.2.2; databaseName=skill; user=sa; password=admin123";

Comment: `"jdbc:mysql://192.168.8.101/skill` and `"jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.0.2.2; databaseName=skill; user=sa; password=admin123"` look different.

Comment: which one is correct sir "jdbc:mysql://192.168.8.101/skill   this one correct. is it Mysql?