# Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2) in logcat

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc

```
String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
String USER = "root";
String PASS = "root";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USER,PASS);
```

I am connecting jdbc mysql but it is unable to connect and i get

error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

in logcate please anybody help me and tell me what should i do?

Comment: Read SO thread [Does JDBC not work with Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7221716/142822)

Comment: Can you help me and send me tutorial for web services..

Comment: Read [1](http://java.dzone.com/articles/invoke-webservices-android),[2](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html), [3](http://www.josecgomez.com/2010/04/30/android-accessing-restfull-web-services-using-json/)

Comment: if possible please solve my jdbc issue..