# Database for android development

Tags: java, android, database

Im searching for good free sql database that can help me to develop my application.
Im only need simple tables like username and password and get the data with android studio.

Comment: Are you looking for an online database ?

Comment: Yes im looking for online database

Answer (score 1):

Android has SQLite built in, you can read more about the library here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

There are also a number of tutorials available as it's a commonly used tool.

Comment: Thanks but im looking for something online that can update from network

Answer (score 1):

I think https://parse.com/ can be used for setting up an online database. It has a user-friendly android API for fetching data.

Comment: I need something simple, i want sql database

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is the Android built it database. This will save your data locally in the phone.

If you want to access a database in a server so all the devices connect to that database and share information among them, then you can choose MySQL for example. Though I have not used MySQL JDBC driver within an Android app you have a detailed question about it here: [Android : Is JDBC supported in Android devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756230/android-is-jdbc-supported-in-android-devices)

If you may relax the pure SQL requirement and dive into NoSQL databases, you may consider MongoDB (which I did use within an Android app). You may even use the services from http://mongolab.com and have your database hosted there.

Comment: Security warning: you'd better think twice before hardcoding the database credentials within your app.

Comment: Do you know any free sql database?

Comment: I have not used free MySQL hosting, but a quick search in Google will point you to solutions as http://haphost.com/free-mysql-hosting/ . If you end up willing to pay, you might look at https://cloud.google.com/sql