# JavaFX + Gluon + MySQL + JDBC

Tags: java, android, mysql, javafx, javafxports

i m trying to write a simple mysql connection code with JDBC to my mysql server on my LAN on OSX.

i have,
– IntelliJ 15 CE
– Gluon Plugins 1.0.1 installed.
– member of apple developper center
– Setting mysql-connector-java.5.1.37.bin.jar in Modules and Libraries (IntelliJ) from Maven Server
and saved under /Library/Java/Extensions

I can create simple IPA and APK and send/start on device with **launchIOSDevice / creataIP/android** (but as i say only simple Hello world)

My Problem is, if i start my code with **TASKS -> RUN** everythings is ok.. I have a succes message on Desktop (OSX), that the connection is OK.

But, if i try same code below to send to my Ipad, i get following errors below.

can anybody help me please, why i cant start this simple code on my ipad?

thanks
erkan kaplan

**my build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.6'

    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'

jfxmobile {

    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        forceLinkClasses = [ 'com.gluonapplication.**.*']
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    }
}
```

**How must i define my "forceLinkClassess" Line for mysql-connector-java?**

**my simple javafx code:**

```
private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.3.188:3306/test_sql";
    private static final String DB_USER = "root";
    private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "myPASSWORT";

    public static Connection connection = null;



    public static Connection getDBConnection (){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
            alertMessage("Connection is OK");
            System.out.println("BAglanti ok");
            return  connection;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("CONNECTION ERROR...");
            alertMessage(e.toString());
        }

    return connection;
    }


    public static void alertMessage(String msg){
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Information");
        alert.setHeaderText("Information");
        alert.setContentText("Ergebnis : " + msg );
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
```

**Error Logs:**

```
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load ‘com.mysql.jdbc.Driver’. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findClassInClasspathForLoader(Native Method)
..........
..........
..........
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run on iOS devices, your classes have to be added with the `forceLinkClasses` option, if you want RoboVM to [link](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_ios_4) them.

That includes the classes on your package, and those on any third dependency you may use.

So this will work:

```
jfxmobile {
    ios {
        forceLinkClasses = [ 'com.gluonapplication.**.*', 'com.mysql.**.*']
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    }
}
```

Note also that you [may](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33599574/3956070) need an older version of the mysql connector.

Finally, `Alert` won't work with JavaFXPorts. JavaFX 8 Dialogs are not yet supported.

Comment: Thanks Jose, i think now is the jdbc included in my project but i have another problem. please look here [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610529/gluon-sample-proect-with-jdbc-dont-work-on-ios-device [/link]