# Gluon Sample Project with JDBC doesn't work on iOS Device

Tags: java, ios, jdbc, javafx, javafxports

i have simple code with Gluon + JDBC.
I can connect this code on Android Device but not on Ipad.

my build.gradle;

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.6'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.0.2'
    iosRuntime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.0.2'
}

mainClassName = 'com.mtt8.version15'

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        }

        ios {
            infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
            forceLinkClasses = ['com.mtt8.**.*', 'com.mysql.**.*']
        }
    }
}
```

and here is JavaCode:

```
private static final String serverIP="192.168.3.188";
    private static final String DB_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.3.188:3306/kasse_sql?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
    private static final String DB_USER = "root";
    private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "MYPASSWORD";

    public static Connection connection = null;
    public static Statement statement = null;
    public static String SQL = null;

    public static PreparedStatement pst = null;


    public static Connection getDBConnection(){

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            //connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.3.188:3306/kasse_sql?user=root&password=MYPASSWORD&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8");
            msg.setText("Connection is OK");
            return  connection;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            msg.setText("Dont Connection");
        }

        return connection;
    }
```

As i say, this code working with Android but not on my Ipad.

I get following errors after **./gradlew launchIOSDevice**

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported character encoding 'Cp1252'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer.readString(Buffer.java:430)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:812)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3269)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1182)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2644)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:144)
    at com.mtt8.version15.getDBConnection(version15.java:58)
    at com.mtt8.version15.start(version15.java:32)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$9.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$7.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$19.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:52)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(Native Method)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java:384)
    at org.javafxports.jfxmobile.ios.BasicLauncher.main(BasicLauncher.java:115)
IOSWindowSystemInterface : setSwapInterval unimp
setSwapInterval(1)
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: FillPgram_Color.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Texture_Color.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Solid_TextureRGB.frag
IOSWindowSystemInterface : setSwapInterval unimp
setSwapInterval(0)
```

i have tried with diffently connection strings but result is same.

Can anybody please say me why my code dont working on Ipad?

thanks
erkan kaplan

Comment: Check your `build.gradle` file, it seems you have included `iOS` within `android` settings. Or is it a typo posting the code?

Comment: my build.gradle is like above...i have add only the line with "iosRuntime"

Comment: That line is not necessary, it will be added from the first dependency. And check this: `jfxmobile { 
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        }
   }
   ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = ['com.mtt8.**.*', 'com.mysql.**.*']
    } 
}`

Comment: Sorr jose, i dont understand you, what you mean.  here is my code: <img src="http://fs5.directupload.net/images/151109/6icx73dd.png width="800" height="600">

Comment: <pre>
dependencies {
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:3.1.14'
}
mainClassName = 'com.mtt8.version15'

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        }
    }

    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = ['com.mtt8.**.*', 'com.mysql.**.*']
    }

}
</pre>   is same result....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's a change in the encoding used in the connector.

This is the latest version that works for me on iOS:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:3.1.12'
}
```

For newer versions (3.1.13+), I find the same exception you see:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported character encoding 'Cp1252'.
at com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils.getBytes(StringUtils.java)
```

Finally, there is a typo on your `build.gradle` file:

```
jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        }
        // typo!! iOS should be outside android!
        ios {
            infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
            forceLinkClasses = ['com.mtt8.**.*', 'com.mysql.**.*']
        }
    }
```

}

Make sure this is how you set your options:

```
jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        }
    }

    ios {
        forceLinkClasses = [ 'com.gluonhq.**.*', 'com.mysql.**.*']
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you Jose, ;.)  I correct my typo and set my IOS Lines in build.gradle....Now i have a connection on Ipad AIR...But only with version 3.1.12.....What you things, its a bug from robovm side or jdbc side?

Comment: I can't tell. Those mysql versions are really old, and they were not intended for mobile devices. As an aside, if you think the answers are valid, please mark them as accepted, so others can find them and benefit from them as well.

Comment: Jose, but the Version 5.0.2 working with Android but not on Ipad..... On Ipad working only Version 3.1.12.....It seems it s bug in robovm...

Comment: Feel free to report it to them, if you think it's that the case.

Comment: ok, i do it and try to open a bug on robovm ....How can accept your answer as valid?  (sorry i m new on stackoverflow)

Comment: Just on the top left of my answer, there's a check you can click. You can vote as well when you have enough reputation.