# JavaFXPorts apk compilation errors

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, javafxports

I have problem with create .apk file. I show error below:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':dex'.
>
>   > warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class   (com.mysql.jdbc.Connection$1) that doesn't come with an
>   >     associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced
>   >     by a   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
>   >     recommended   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
>   >     up-to-date compiler   and without specifying any "-target" type
>   >     options. The consequence of ignoring   this warning is that reflective
>   >     operations on this class will incorrectly   indicate that it is *not*
>   >     an inner class.   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an
>   >     anonymous inner class   (com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionProperties$1) that
>   >     doesn't come with an   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This
>   >     class was probably produced by a   compiler that did not target the
>   >     modern .class file format. The recommended   solution is to recompile
>   >     the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler   and without
>   >     specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>   >     this warning is that reflective operations on this class will
>   >     incorrectly   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.   warning:
>   >     Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   >     (com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$1) that doesn't come with an
>   >     associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced
>   >     by a   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
>   >     recommended   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
>   >     up-to-date compiler   and without specifying any "-target" type
>   >     options. The consequence of ignoring   this warning is that reflective
>   >     operations on this class will incorrectly   indicate that it is *not*
>   >     an inner class.   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an
>   >     anonymous inner class   (com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$2) that
>   >     doesn't come with an   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This
>   >     class was probably produced by a   compiler that did not target the
>   >     modern .class file format. The recommended   solution is to recompile
>   >     the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler   and without
>   >     specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>   >     this warning is that reflective operations on this class will
>   >     incorrectly   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.   warning:
>   >     Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   >     (com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$3) that doesn't come with an
>   >     associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced
>   >     by a   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
>   >     recommended   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
>   >     up-to-date compiler   and without specifying any "-target" type
>   >     options. The consequence of ignoring   this warning is that reflective
>   >     operations on this class will incorrectly   indicate that it is *not*
>   >     an inner class.   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an
>   >     anonymous inner class   (com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$4) that
>   >     doesn't come with an   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This
>   >     class was probably produced by a   compiler that did not target the
>   >     modern .class file format. The recommended   solution is to recompile
>   >     the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler   and without
>   >     specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>   >     this warning is that reflective operations on this class will
>   >     incorrectly   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.   warning:
>   >     Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   >     (com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$5) that doesn't come with an
>   >     associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced
>   >     by a   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
>   >     recommended   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
>   >     up-to-date compiler   and without specifying any "-target" type
>   >     options. The consequence of ignoring   this warning is that reflective
>   >     operations on this class will incorrectly   indicate that it is *not*
>   >     an inner class.   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an
>   >     anonymous inner class   (com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$6) that
>   >     doesn't come with an   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This
>   >     class was probably produced by a   compiler that did not target the
>   >     modern .class file format. The recommended   solution is to recompile
>   >     the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler   and without
>   >     specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>   >     this warning is that reflective operations on this class will
>   >     incorrectly   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.   warning:
>   >     Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   >     (com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$7) that doesn't come with an
>   >     associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced
>   >     by a   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
>   >     recommended   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
>   >     up-to-date compiler   and without specifying any "-target" type
>   >     options. The consequence of ignoring   this warning is that reflective
>   >     operations on this class will incorrectly   indicate that it is *not*
>   >     an inner class.   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an
>   >     anonymous inner class   (com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$8) that
>   >     doesn't come with an   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This
>   >     class was probably produced by a   compiler that did not target the
>   >     modern .class file format. The recommended   solution is to recompile
>   >     the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler   and without
>   >     specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>   >     this warning is that reflective operations on this class will
>   >     incorrectly   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.   warning:
>   >     Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   >     (com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$9) that doesn't come with an
>   >     associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced
>   >     by a   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
>   >     recommended   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
>   >     up-to-date compiler   and without specifying any "-target" type
>   >     options. The consequence of ignoring   this warning is that reflective
>   >     operations on this class will incorrectly   indicate that it is *not*
>   >     an inner class.   Uncaught translation error:
>   >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   >     Java heap space   1 error; aborting
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 8 mins 14.858 secs [sts] Build failed
>   org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using
>   Gradle distribution
>   'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip'.     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:57)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:71)
>     at
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.TaskUtil.execute(TaskUtil.java:117)
>     at
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.launch.GradleProcess$1.doit(GradleProcess.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable$1.run(GradleRunnable.java:53)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55) Caused
>   by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution
>   failed for task ':dex'.   at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:77)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:108)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:30)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)    at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
>   Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution
>   failed for task ':dex'.   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
>     ... 32 more Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: warning:
>   Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.mysql.jdbc.Connection$1) that doesn't come with an associated
>   EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
>   recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
>   up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options.
>   The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations
>   on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner
>   class. warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner
>   class (com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionProperties$1) that doesn't come with
>   an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably
>   produced by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file
>   format. The recommended solution is to recompile the class from
>   source, using an up-to-date compiler and without specifying any
>   "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring this warning is
>   that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly indicate
>   that it is *not* an inner class. warning: Ignoring InnerClasses
>   attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$1) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced
>   by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
>   recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
>   up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options.
>   The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations
>   on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner
>   class. warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner
>   class (com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$2) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced
>   by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
>   recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
>   up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options.
>   The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations
>   on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner
>   class. warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner
>   class (com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$3) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced
>   by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
>   recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
>   up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options.
>   The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations
>   on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner
>   class. warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner
>   class (com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$4) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced
>   by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
>   recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
>   up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options.
>   The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations
>   on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner
>   class. warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner
>   class (com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$5) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced
>   by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
>   recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
>   up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options.
>   The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations
>   on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner
>   class. warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner
>   class (com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$6) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced
>   by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
>   recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
>   up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options.
>   The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations
>   on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner
>   class. warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner
>   class (com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$7) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced
>   by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
>   recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
>   up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options.
>   The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations
>   on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner
>   class. warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner
>   class (com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$8) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced
>   by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
>   recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
>   up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options.
>   The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations
>   on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner
>   class. warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner
>   class (com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$9) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced
>   by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
>   recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
>   up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options.
>   The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations
>   on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner
>   class. Uncaught translation error:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   Java heap space 1 error; aborting     at
>   org.javafxports.jfxmobile.plugin.android.task.Dex.dex(Dex.groovy:57)
>     at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
>     ... 55 more

If anyone knows how fix this please for help.

this is my build.gradle:

```
> buildscript {
>     repositories {
>         jcenter()
>         mavenCentral()
>         maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
>     }
>     dependencies { classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.6' } }
> 
> apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'
> 
> 
> repositories {
>     jcenter()
>     mavenCentral()
>     maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
>     maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases' } }
> 
> ext.CHARM_DOWN_VERSION = "1.0.0"
> 
> dependencies {
>     compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:3.1.12'
>     compile 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.9.0-SNAPSHOT'
> 
>     compile "com.gluonhq:charm-down-common:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"
>     desktopRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-down-desktop:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"
>     androidRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-down-android:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"
>     iosRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-down-ios:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION" }
> 
> 
> 
> 
> mainClassName = 'com.orden.OrdenApplication'
> 
> jfxmobile {
>     android {
>         manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
>         androidSdk = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/'
>         packagingOptions {
>             exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
>         }
>     }
> 
>     ios {
>         infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
>         forceLinkClasses = ['com.mtt8.**.*', 'com.mysql.**.*', 'SQLite.**.*', 'com.gluonhq.**.*']
>     }
> 
> }
```

Comment: Are you adding mysql to your Android project? Not all the latest versions work on Android. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610529/gluon-sample-project-with-jdbc-doesnt-work-on-ios-device). Try a lower version or try [SQLite](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/gluon-SQLite)

Comment: This solution failed. I nedd to compile android application. There is ios problem.

Comment: Your build versions are quite outdated. See the SQLite sample build I've mentioned for latest versions, and how to include the right sql driver on each platform.

Comment: Ok problem solved. Thanks for any tips