# Why Vs Code does't highlight color in integrated terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am using bash terminal in Vs Code, as:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

I notes that some of the words does't highlights, as shown:

[image: vs code]

But same directory using Bash terminal looks like this:

[image: bash]

Notes: I am using window 8.1

Any idea??? May be some setting, or plugin for Vs Code.

Comment: Have you seen the GluonSQLite [sample](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/gluon-SQLite) and [docs](http://docs.gluonhq.com/samples/gluonsqlite/)? It explains why it uses sqlite instead of mysql. Still you can use mysql in your Android app, but not all the versions are supported, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485466/javafxports-mysqldb-driver-include-in-project-dex-error/33599574#33599574). Anyway, you should avoid accessing your database from your app directly.

Comment: I have changes my question...

Comment: You should have created a new post, your new question is completely different.