# How to get Image from mysql glob type

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I created a DB in mysql workbunch and i stor picture in it as as type blob.
Now I want to use this picture in my app,

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                try(Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sys", "root", "Elior204")){
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT img FROM Sentences where id=1");
                       ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    Blob b =rs.getBlob(1);
                    int blobLength = (int) b.length();
                    byte[] blobAsBytes = b.getBytes(1, blobLength);
                    Bitmap btm =BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blobAsBytes,0,blobAsBytes.length);
                    image.setImageBitmap(btm );
                    con.close();
```

The question is, how I continue?

Comment: you can't access mysql directly in Android.you need one web service to access the mysql data.

Comment: Sure, you can, if you [include the right permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18843518/783412)

Comment: נשמה של אבא דבר איתי כפרה

Comment: `jdbc:mysql://localhost` will never work within an Android device... Unless you actually running mysql server there

Answer (score 0):

```
java.sql.Blob blob = rs.getBlob(1);
byte[] imageContents = blob.getBytes(1, new Integer(blob.length()).intValue());
```

Now you can manipulate it as you wish.

Per your comment, you want to display it in your application, to accomplish this, add an ImageView to your layout and use the following code:

```
 image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

 button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImage);
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
          java.io.File tmpFileForImage = java.io.File.createTemporaryFile("image", ".png"); // or whatever your extension happens to be
          java.io.BufferedOutputStream bos = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(new java.io.FileOutputStream(tmpFileForImage);
          bos.write(imageContents);
          bos.close();
          image.setImageResource(tmpFileForImage.getAbsolutePath());
    });
```

Untested, but should get you on the right track. If you need further assistance, leave another comment.

Comment: I want to display the picture on my app, how i do it?

Comment: I edit my question, and it still not working do you know why?

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: You're missing the need for Asynctask and the fact that mobile devices should not really be using long lived JDBC objects