# Can i connect to mysql from android without any webservice, And Using JDBC?

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc, service

I want to connect to mysql without any php service, is that possible?

Comment: consider j2ee service, c# service, socket service

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7221716/276263 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/7221969/276263

Answer (score 0):

Use jdbc like this:

```
String url = "http://localhost/SomeDB";
String user = "someUser";
String pass = "somePass";

Class.forName(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver);
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet = st.executeQuery(SELECT * FROM Table);

String result1 = ResultSet.getString(0);
```

For the

```
Class.forName(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver);
```

You need the sql connect android library (jar file), just search on Google ;)