# Android JDBC connector

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc

I'm developing an app that inserts data into database without using any webservies. I've created a database on my notebook with MySQL workbench. I am able to insert data into the database using emulator, but I cannot insert data into the database using my phone.
I have changed the path from

```
jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2:3306/ with jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/
```

xx.xx.xx.xx is from ipconfig of my localhost machine. I've tried again with emulator and I'm still able to insert data, but when I try with phone I cannot. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access a MySQL DB from Android natively. EDIT: Actually you may be able to use JDBC, but it is not recommended (or may not work?) ... see

- [Android JDBC not working: ClassNotFoundException on driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221620/android-jdbc-not-working-classnotfoundexception-on-driver/7221716#7221716)

> Android cannot connect directly to the database server. Therefore we need to create a simple web service that will pass the requests to the database and will return the response.

See this tutorial:

- [how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm gonna use REST API