# Can we connect remote MySQL database in Android using JDBC?

Tags: java, android, mysql, rest, jdbc

I am developing a client-server application which requires remote database connection.

I know that tutorials on the web and more people are using PHP to interact with MySQL. But, I am not so good at PHP and my prior experience is with Core Java, Swing and JDBC.

Can anyone guide me if it is possible to connect remote MySQL database using JAVA JDBC APIs in Android application?

Comment: I don't know what kind of tutorial you're reading, but for an Android app to interact with a database you should use RESTful services. These services may be built using PHP, Java or another programming language.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I did seach on both - REST for PHP and RESTLET for JAVA...But, I am very novice to client-server applications. I don't know How can we use JDBC with RESTLET webservices.

Comment: You should focus on one thing at a hand. Search for a simple tutorial on how to build a RESTful service using Java, probably using Tomcat or Jetty. Then, after you find this RESTful service is backed by a class and a method, you may notice that you can use JDBC inside this class/method and evolve the purpose of your service. Then this may evolve into a layered architecture and continue evolving. And more importantly: you will learn while practicing all this stuff.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Basically: you can connect to your MySQL (or whatever you use) server, but **you should not** do this directly from your Android application.

Reasons:

1. Android applications can be decompiled, and the client will have credentials to access to your database. If using the right hacking tools like [Backtrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/), then this malicious client can access, connect and exploit the data in your database.
2. If your application is for clients all around the world, then the clients should open and maintain a connection to your database per operation or set of operations. Opening a physical database connection takes a lot of time, even when your pc client is in a LAN next to the database engine server. Now, imagine opening a connection from a country in the other side of the world e.g. China or Japan or from a country in South America like Brazil or Peru (where I live).

For these 2 reasons I can come up with, it's a bad idea even trying to connect to MySQL or any other database engine directly from your phone device.

How to solve this problem? Use a service oriented architecture where you will have at least two applications:

1. Service provider application. This application will create and publish web services (preferably RESTful) and may establish policies to consume the web services like user authentication and authorization. This application will also connect to the database and execute CRUD operations against it.
2. Service consumer application. This would be your Android (or any other mobile) application.

From your question, you're focusing on the point 1. As I've said in my comments, you can create a Web application in Java, create a RESTful service there, which boils down to a POJO (plain old java object) that has a method per service. In this method, since it's plain Java after all, you can add other functionality like JDBC usage.

Here's a kickoff example using Jersey, Jackson (JSON library) and JDBC:

```
@Path("/product")
public class ProductRestService {

    @GET
    @Path("/list")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
        Connection con = ...; //retrieve your database connection
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id, name FROM product");
        while (rs.next()) {
            Product product = new Product();
            product.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            product.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            productList.add(product);
        }
        //ALWAYS close the resources
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
        return productList;
    }
}
```

You can check for further configurations of the Java web application in a tutorial like [mkyong's](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-rs-tutorials/) or [Vogella's](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html) or any other of your like (it's too much info to place in this answer).

Note that then this application can evolve into a layered application, and the JDBC code will go in a DAO class, and then the `ProductRestService` class will access to the database through this DAO class. Here's another kickoff example:

```
public class ProductDao {
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
        Connection con = ...; //retrieve your database connection
        //the rest of the code explained above...
        return productList;
    }
}

@Path("/product")
public class ProductRestService {
    @GET
    @Path("/list")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        ProductDao productDao = new ProductDao();
        return productDao.getProducts();
    }
}
```

And you can apply other changes to this project as well as is evolving.

> Can you say me what PHP does here? (if I develop with PHP)

Instead of writing the Service provider application in Java (as shown above), you can do it in PHP. Or in Python, Ruby, C#, Scala or any other programming language that provides this technology to you. Again, I'm not sure what kind of tutorial you're reading, but this should be explained somewhere and explain that for the purposes of that tutorial you will create the services using PHP. If you feel more comfortable writing these services in Java rather than in PHP or any other language, there's no problem. Your android app doesn't really care which technology is used to produce the web services, it will only care about consuming the services and that the data from them can be consumed.

Comment: Can you suggest any good article about connecting Android application to MySQL database using jersey web services?

Comment: @userX I found this while searching on my SEO: http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-restful-webservice-tutorial-how-to-call-restful-webservice-in-android-part-3/ Tutorial TL;DR the method that invokes the external web service is `invokeWS`. I do not support that tutorial.

Comment: cant a webservice be ddos attacked, so how is it perfect? Yes it protects pw, but wont i still need oauth or yet another layer of grief? I am leaning toward using mysql-procedures instead of webservice. That way I can use their IP address to throttle usage, bad behavior. Yes, IP is spoofable, but after fighting 10 years with a php intermediary solution, I am leaning toward mysql-procedures....

Comment: @jim Any service available through the web can be attacked using DDoS or any other technique. Just connect your device to an access point like a WAN and then use a sniffer to see the network traffic, you will see the server that your device realize calls, even via IP, then DDoS that server, no matter what is there. Using MySQL procedures won't change this fact.

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to do it but not recommended. I have done it before as I was in the same boat as you so I will share some code.

I used this jdbc jar specifically: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wr06rtjqv0q1vgs/mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar?dl=0

now for the code:

```
    package com.example.test.databaseapp;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:xxxx/DBNAME";
        static final String user = "client";
        static final String pass = "password";
        public static List<objClass> objList;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            new Download(MainActivity.this, internalUrl).execute(); //async task for getting data from db
        }
    }
```

Now for my async task:

```
public class Download extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    Context context;
    private String url;

    public Download(Context context, String url) {
        this.context = context;
        this.url = url;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "",
                "Please wait, getting database...");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            java.sql.Statement st = con.createStatement();
            java.sql.ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from table");
            list = new ArrayList<objClass>();

            while (rs.next()) {
                String field= rs.getString("field");
                MainActivity.playerList.add(new objectClass(field));
            }      
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Complete";
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result.equals("Complete")) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to include internet permissions in the manifest.
Feel free to ask more questions about my code if you have any.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access a MySQL DB from Android natively. EDIT: Actually you may be able to use JDBC, but it is not recommended (or may not work?) ... see [Android JDBC not working: ClassNotFoundException on driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221620/android-jdbc-not-working-classnotfoundexception-on-driver/7221716#7221716)

See

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/8339-connect-android-mysql-database-tutorial.html

> Android cannot connect directly to the database server. Therefore we
>   need to create a simple web service that will pass the requests to the
>   database and will return the response.

http://codeoncloud.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-mysql-client.html

For most [good] users this might be fine. But imagine you get a hacker that gets a hold of your program. I've decompiled my own applications and its scary what I've seen. What if they get your username / password to your database and wreak havoc? Bad.

Comment: @xyz as I noted in my comments to your question, PHP is not required, that's what the tutorial explains to you. The RESTful services may be written in PHP, Java, Python, Ruby, C# or any other programming language that supports creating a set of RESTful services. A web service client (in this case, your Android app) is not tied to the technology where the web service was created.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Can you say me what PHP does here? (if I develop with PHP)