# AWS RDS connection with android

Tags: android, mysql, amazon-web-services, android-webservice

I don't know whether I'm in right way or not. After a long googling I'm posting this. My requirement is, My android app needs to get connected with Amazon RDS database directly. I do not know any other possibilities. What i have done is got connected by JDBC connection from Android to RDS. Is this way correct or not. please help me out.

Note : There is no choice between server server DB : Amazon RDS(Mysql)

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you read this link on [The Stack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26471486/) and the article from [AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html)

Comment: @Drew Thanks, This is fine i knew. it is not good practice at all but client forces me to do this. I dont think the question is duplicated my question is, Im asking amzon have any other service to connect with amzon RDS..? without server scripting..?

Comment: What is your definition of server scripting. You also realize you just changed your question by your last comment