# Can i access local host.?

Tags: android

i have created static ip using loopback adapter on windows 7 , i have also created my database on wamp server, how can I access that on my android device without using a router or internet but just my laptop and my cellphone .Any sugestion and solution are appritiated thankyou.

Comment: Not possible. If I could only access this site without connecting to the internet!

Comment: hey can u tell me any easiest way to do this task with least resources... thanx for the reply

Comment: the computer and the phone must be on the same local network, if that's possible I'll consider posting an answer

Comment: yes i can connect phone and my system with a same router

Comment: I just re-read your question. Are you trying to connect to the database directly from your android app? If yes don't do it. Create a REST API on the server, and then connect to it using your android app. You should find many tutorials online.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we connect remote MySQL database in Android using JDBC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470117/can-we-connect-remote-mysql-database-in-android-using-jdbc)