# Working with data on Android

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a school project for an Android App that needs to track the nutrition intake of an individual based on both macro and micro nutrients.

The list of activities that I plan to include consists of:

1. User Login/Registration
2. Taking personal information like age, gender, height and weight to get the total calories, macro (carbo, protein and fats) and micro (vitamins and minerals) that the user need
3. Connecting to a webservice (currently looking at USDA/nutritionix/fatsecret database API) for them to search food for their meals
4. At the same time, have option to manually add details of their food's nutritional information
5. Calculate the balance of calories, macronutrients and micronutrients that they have
6. Display a chart to show the daily and weekly breakdown of nutritional intakes.

Given my limited experience in database and Android app development, I am quite clueless on how to handle these large amount of datas transferring within the app.

I am unfortunately tight of schedule (about 1 month) to explore all different options. As such, I would like to seek advice on what I should focus more on learning from the various options available (such as MySQL, SQL Lite, Firebase, or passing data between activities such as shared preferences/ Extras etc.) for the different components of the app listed.

Comment: Seems that sqlLite is supported on Android. Would be the place to start: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm, Also:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: Since it seems the app's data is user specific, something like [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) would work. However, if you need a database to store data shared between multiple users, you'll need to make a web service, and call the [web service](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112381/Step-by-Step-Method-to-Access-Webservice-from-Andr) from your app.

Comment: Just for reference, the first time I was in your situation, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26471486/3040381) answer gave me clarity

Comment: Thank you so much for the head up and relevant references for me to start on! Will heed your advices! :)