# How to connect a Android app to a MySql database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

My question is simple, almost all the answers I find have been deprecated. What is currently the best way to connect an Android App to a MySQL database?

Comment: Take a look [at that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26471486/2256527)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we connect remote MySQL database in Android using JDBC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470117/can-we-connect-remote-mysql-database-in-android-using-jdbc)

Answer (score 3):

I once created an application following this tutorial on **Youtube**
[How to Connect Android with PHP, MySQL - Best Android Studio Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4eFBQmWs8Q&t=1684s)

I would like you to watch this, it is gonna help you a lot.

Please let me know if it helps you!!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the general opinion will be any kind of api to mediate between the database and the app. Never connect directly to it. 
A REST api served by a php server should make it, given you added the php tag on purpose

Comment: I did add php on purpose, my project has a fully functioning php website, and I am attempting to create an app for it now. I know not to connect directly to the databse, but the tutorials I found using a web service use deprecated code.

Comment: Have you read this?
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: I have created a PHP script "api.php" that will take care of exposing your MySQL through a REST API via PHP, see [this repo](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api/) on Github.