# How to connect to a database in Android?

Tags: android, mysql, sql

I'm trying to connect to MySQL in Android:

```
try{
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.105:3306/qrdb";
            String username = "root";
            String password = "****";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

            String sqlCommand = "CREATE TABLE items (Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(20), price INT)";

            try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)){

                Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
                // создание таблицы
                statement.executeUpdate(sqlCommand);

                Log.i("mytag","Database has been created!");
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            // handle any errors
            Log.i("mytag","SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            Log.i("mytag","SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            Log.i("mytag","VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Log.i("mytag","Connection failed...");

            Log.i("mytag", "" + ex);
        }
```

Throws an exception:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

MySQL Connector/J 8.0 is installed. In the usual Java project, everything works.

Comment: or tell me alternative methods

Comment: I need to connect to any database remotely

Comment: Just as a side note, directly connecting to a MySQL database from an Android app via jdbc is considered [very bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470117/can-we-connect-remote-mysql-database-in-android-using-jdbc)

Comment: so how should it be? through what?

Comment: Store your data locally using an SQLite or Room database, and sync with your remote server using a REST API. That way you can better handle situations arising from intermittent data connectivity, as you often find on mobile devices.

Comment: like @MichaelDodd said You need to make some kind of server side API ('s) (REST, SOAP, XML-RPC or Websockets as communication protocols) on which a Android app can connect

Comment: Do you have a good example, example, doc? I don't understand how to google it.

Comment: I'm from Russia. Russian google is not searched

Comment: Here's a link to [documentation on data storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage#db)