# mysql driver class not found exception

Tags: android, mysql

I'm trying to use MySQL while learning Android, but this class not found exception occurs. I have imported the MySQL connecter jar file into my project, and I have set it up. I googled about the problem but only got a tomcat solution of the same problem but I still don't know how to solve this in Android.

```
 private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

    String msg = "";
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://"+
            DBStrings.DATABASE_URL +"/"+
            DBStrings.DATABASE_NAME;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
    progressTextView.setText("Connecting to database");

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,DBStrings.USERNAME,DBStrings.PASSWORD);

            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM medicine";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while(rs.next()){
                Integer ID = rs.getInt("ID");
                String name = rs.getString("Name");
                Integer date = rs.getInt("Date");
                medID.add(ID);
                names.add(name);
                medDate.add(date);

            }

            msg = "complete!";

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();

        }catch (SQLException connERROR)
        {
            msg = "An exception was thrown for JDBC";
            connERROR.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException classERROR)
        {
            msg = "Class not found exception";
            classERROR.printStackTrace();
        }finally {

        }

        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: As a side note, using JDBC from an Android device [is generally a **very** bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26471486/469080). Use local storage and a middle-man API to sync.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to use local storage later, but I still want to know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use JDBC from an android device, just use J2EE servlets (simplest solution if you want to code  in JAVA), and call these servlet from android through HTTP (you can use Retrofit Library to make these calls https://square.github.io/retrofit).