# android app sql server 2012 connectivity using jdbc driver

Tags: android, jdbc

i am using jdbc driver library to connect my android  app to sql server 2014.it gives me error  sometimes while executing query.Error is mention below

***cannot open database requested by the login. the login failed for user***

Here is code for connecting android app to sql server 2014

```
String connectionURL;
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        connectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"
                + user.getServerIP()
                + ";databaseName="
                + user.getDbName()
                + ";user="
                + user.getUserName()
                + ";password="
                + user.getPassword()
                + ";";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
        con.close();
        return con;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Timber.e(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
```

Please help me out.

Comment: You should not connect directly to a database server using a JDBC driver. See also [Can we connect remote MySQL database in Android using JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470117/can-we-connect-remote-mysql-database-in-android-using-jdbc)

Comment: according to requirement all the database is in offline mode so i need to connect android app using local wifi

Comment: How can the database be in an 'offline' mode, when it is a remote database?

Comment: sql server is installed on local pc in shop and i am connecting it with local wifi using local pc IP address