# How to connect Postgresql with Android app in android Studio and later insert app data into database table?

Tags: android, postgresql, android-studio

This is my code. I've to insert device id into Postgresql database table. How do I connect android app with Postgresql and perform sql operations?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        String id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        textview.setText(id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of connecting directly to PostGreSQL, you can connect via the server-side application. For example, let's say we have created a node.js application. On the Android side, all you have to do is send the data to the server-side application. It is very simple to connect with the database in server-side applications.

Comment: I want direct connection with PostgreSQL. How do I create direct connection? Should I implement JDBC?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470117/can-we-connect-remote-mysql-database-in-android-using-jdbc check this