# Is using JDBC secure for android?

Tags: android, security, jdbc

I would like to know if it is secure to use JDBC to connect into the MSSQL database to retrieve the data  instead of using HTTP.

I found this AceQL in which it uses only JDBC and according to what I read from the website, it provides some "security"
 http://www.aceql.com/why-secure-jdbc-over-http-for-android-swing-javafx.html

but when I make research on the security of JDBC used in android phones, I found out that it is not recommended.
[Android JDBC not working: ClassNotFoundException on driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221620/android-jdbc-not-working-classnotfoundexception-on-driver/7221716#7221716)

So would someone please give me some advice as, which one is better? Is it okay to use JDBC?

Comment: What happened to AceQL.  It looks like such a good idea.  Not much recent.  Should I be putting effort into this?