# Websocket does not seem to connect

Tags: java, android, websocket

```
package com.example.chat;     //client for a server


import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button b1;
    private EditText t1,t2;
    public StringBuffer str=new StringBuffer();
    public WebSocketClient mWebSocketClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            connectWebSocket();
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        runWebSocket();
    }

    public void runWebSocket(){
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        t1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        t2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        str.insert(0,"");
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendNewMessage(v);
            }
        });
    }

    public void connectWebSocket() {
        URI uri;
        try {
            uri = new URI("ws://192.168.10.77:8080/Chat/EchoAnnotation");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Opened");
                mWebSocketClient.send("hello server");
                str.append("hello server \n");

                t2.setText(str);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String s) {
                final String message = s;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        str.append("Server says: " + message+ "\n");
                        t2.setText(str);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Closed " + s);
                str.append("WebSocket is closed");
                t2.setText(str);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
                str.append("there is some error in the WebSocket");
                t2.setText(str);
            }
        };
        mWebSocketClient.connect();
    }

    public void sendNewMessage(View view){
        str.append("Client says: "+t1.getText().toString()+"\n");
        mWebSocketClient.send(t1.getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

logcat:

```
06-11 05:08:01.601: W/dalvikvm(1045): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/chat/MainActivity$2; (1380)
06-11 05:08:01.601: W/dalvikvm(1045): Link of class 'Lcom/example/chat/MainActivity$2;' failed
06-11 05:08:01.601: E/dalvikvm(1045): Could not find class 'com.example.chat.MainActivity$2', referenced from method com.example.chat.MainActivity.connectWebSocket
06-11 05:08:01.601: W/dalvikvm(1045): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1262 (Lcom/example/chat/MainActivity$2;) in Lcom/example/chat/MainActivity;
06-11 05:08:01.601: D/dalvikvm(1045): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0007
06-11 05:08:01.641: I/dalvikvm(1045): Could not find method org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient.send, referenced from method com.example.chat.MainActivity.sendNewMessage
06-11 05:08:01.641: W/dalvikvm(1045): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9762: Lorg/java_websocket/client/WebSocketClient;.send (Ljava/lang/String;)V
06-11 05:08:01.641: D/dalvikvm(1045): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0030
06-11 05:08:01.641: W/dalvikvm(1045): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/chat/MainActivity$2; (1380)
06-11 05:08:01.651: W/dalvikvm(1045): Link of class 'Lcom/example/chat/MainActivity$2;' failed
06-11 05:08:01.661: D/dalvikvm(1045): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x24e7 at 0x09 in Lcom/example/chat/MainActivity;.connectWebSocket
06-11 05:08:02.221: D/dalvikvm(1045): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 104K, 5% free 3261K/3432K, paused 38ms, total 40ms
06-11 05:08:02.251: D/AndroidRuntime(1045): Shutting down VM
06-11 05:08:02.251: W/dalvikvm(1045): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a83ba8)
06-11 05:08:02.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 05:08:02.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): Process: com.example.chat, PID: 1045
06-11 05:08:02.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.chat.MainActivity$2
06-11 05:08:02.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at com.example.chat.MainActivity.connectWebSocket(MainActivity.java:67)
06-11 05:08:02.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at com.example.chat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
06-11 05:08:02.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-11 05:08:02.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-11 05:08:02.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
06-11 05:08:02.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
06-11 05:08:02.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-11 05:08:02.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-11 05:08:02.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-11 05:08:02.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-11 05:08:02.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
06-11 05:08:02.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 05:08:02.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-11 05:08:02.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-11 05:08:02.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-11 05:08:02.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-11 05:08:07.281: I/Process(1045): Sending signal. PID: 1045 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the library for `org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient` is not available:

The logcat messages

> Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/chat/MainActivity$2;

and

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.chat.MainActivity$2

indicate that the anonymous class you are creating in this piece of code

```
mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
    ...
}
```

Cannot be created, because the class definition for `WebSocketClient` was not found.

Some answers indicate you should check your build path settings:

- In Eclipse, make sure that *Android Private Libraries* is checked for Export ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16641790), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16603954))
- In Android Studio, make sure that the library is on the path; select *Add As Library* from the context menu ([3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28741690))

Comment: I would not know a workaround, but adding the library to the classpath would be a solution. I've adapted the answer accordingly.