# CachedRowSet on Android?

Tags: android, mysql, resultset, cachedrowset

there is any way to use a CachedRowSet or similar on Android? I'd like to save my ResultSet's values into any object independent of the Statement, and then close my Statement without losing the information that I've retrieved.

I'm using jdbc MySQL 5.1.27 connector.

Thanks in advance.

My main problem is that in some methods I'm getting various ResultSets and while I'm working with them I can see how my tablet is working slower. I want to close every Statement I've opened and keep working with the ResultSets, but the problem is that the ResultSets are dependant of the Statemenents, so if I close the Statement, I'm losing my ResultSet.

I want to use something like 'CachedRowSet', what is supossed to work like a ResultSet but without having to stay connected to the database.

I use JDBC cause the app works in closed networks, retrieving information directly from the server.

Comment: CachedRowSet, ResultSet, Statement, what are you talking about?

Comment: I'd like to use CachedRowSet or something similar on Android.

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: I can't find there what I'm looking for =/

Comment: what about that: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db ? "Every SQLite query will return a Cursor that points to all the rows found by the query. The Cursor is always the mechanism with which you can navigate results from a database query and read rows and columns.

For sample apps that demonstrate how to use SQLite databases in Android, see the Note Pad and Searchable Dictionary applications."

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221620/android-jdbc-not-working-classnotfoundexception-on-driver/7221716#7221716

Comment: Yeah, I know, but that's not what I mean. 

I'll explain it better on the question.

Comment: The problem is that I must use jdbc, even if I dont want to use it, is not my project