# App crash when try to connect to DB with JDBC

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio, jdbc

I want to get some values from my database, but when I click button (void ButtonClick) my app crashes.

That's my code:

```
public void ButtonClick() throws Exception {
    getConnection();
}

public Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    try {
        String username = "*******";
        String password = "*******";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://http://**.***.***.***:3306/UserDB";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        Statement statement = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE 'UserDB'";
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while (result.next()) {
            String name = result.getString("Username");
            int id = result.getInt("ID");
            int points = result.getInt("Points");
            Toast.makeText(this, name + " " + id + " " + points, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return  conn;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return null;
}
```

(I don't know what's the error because my AVD don't work)

Thanks for help!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Please add code here instead of pasting an external link

Comment: Alex Mamo, i don't know what is the error. My AVD don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Java 7, there is no need to use `forName()` method. You are creating a new instance in this way and in the same time you are trying to create a connection using `DriverManager.getConnection()`.

So in order to solve this, just remove the instantiation of the driver using `forName()` method.

Seeing the screen-shot, please note that you can't access a MySQL database from Android natively. Actually you may be able to use JDBC, but it is not recommended. Please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221620/android-jdbc-not-working-classnotfoundexception-on-driver/7221716#7221716)

Hope it helps.

Comment: i just ran into this problem. the recommended way for database access is apparently a RESTful service sitting between the app and the database.