# JSR/RET are not supported with computerFrames

Tags: java, android, mysql

Im facing error **JSR/RET are not supported with computeFrames**

I think it because of my "**mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin**"

**dependencies**

```
 compile project(':mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin')
```

**My Activity**

```
private static final String TAG = "report";
private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.16/apitest";
private static final String USER = "zzz";
private static final String PASS = "zzz";

public void sampletest(View view) {
    Send objSend = new Send();
    objSend.execute("");
}

private class Send extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String msg = "";
    String text = reportname.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            if (conn == null) {
                msg = "Connection goes wrong";
            }
            else {
                String query = "INSERT INTO name (test) VALUES ('"+text+"')";
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                stmt.executeUpdate(query);
                msg = "Successfully insert!!!!!";
            }
            conn.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            msg = "Connection goes wrong";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return msg;
    }
}
```

[Attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8Cz0.png)

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7221716/5110595)

Comment: It is a bug in Android Studio / Gradle.  Apparently fixed in 2.3.