# Android Studio Connection with the database on physical device via XAMPP

Tags: java, android, database, xampp, ipv4

I'm writing an app, which connects to the database, and sends a basic query. Till now I did all my tests on `Android Studio Emulator` and it worked fine, until I tried it on my phone, which can't connect to the database.

```
try{
            String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.12/mydb";
            miastoItemList =new ArrayList<>();
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", 
"test");
            Statement statement = c.createStatement();
            String s = "SELECT * FROM city";
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(s);
}
```

Comment: i think you have to change it to `String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.12:PortNumber/mydb";` to make it work.

Comment: Unfortunately still no response from the database.

Comment: can you try `192.168.0.12:PortNumber` in your mobile browser? Make sure devide and localhost are on same network.

Comment: Yes I tried and it connects through a browser, I even enabled access to phpmyadmin in httpd-xampp.conf file. Still no response in the app though.

Comment: I tried Apache port and it worked, I'll try to do it with the app and will post results in a moment

Comment: Still no answer from the database, tried two Apache ports and MySql one

Comment: **I tried Apache port and it worked** ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device

Comment: In the XAMPP panel I've got 2 Apache ports one :80 and the other one :443 + I've got one more in the MySql port 3306. Only the 80 worked

Comment: 80 worked means? you got desired data? Your phone and host machine in same network? `192.168.0.12:MySQLPortNumber` on browser shows you what?

Comment: Only after adding :80 the website worked. After adding :3306 I have no response and after adding :443 ( which is second port for the apache) I've got Error 400. But still no response on the app

Comment: try `192.168.0.12:8080` on app

Comment: Still no response from the database on app, when I debug it, it just stops after reaching line with Connection c. So nothing new

Comment: Thats weird. I believe you have internet permission, since  you said it is working on emulator. Do you have any exceptions on log?

Comment: ' Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.' something like that

Comment: I did some research. Could not find anything, but found out that using jdbc is not a good practice on android according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7221716/7557205). So it is better to develop an api (web service which returns required data) than opening a database connection from android device, and doing database operations with that connection.  Here is a neat [tutorial](http://androidbash.com/connecting-android-app-to-a-database-using-php-and-mysql/) on how to do that right.

Comment: Well, thank you for your help Aswin :)

Comment: Good luck, mate

Comment: That little neat tutorial works, thanks :)

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Comment: You need to configure Remote SQL in your MySQL server. But, remember dbc is not a good practice on android - please go through API backend services.