# Android Program crashes before even opening

Tags: android

I'm just starting to use Android Studio and allready having trouble, I need to conect to a database on sqlserver via my cellphone, but it crashes before the whole thing starts to work, I need a little help please, here is the code:

```
  import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Farmaciapp extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText edtMed =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtMedicamento);
    String ConsulMed = edtMed.getText().toString();
    public void Meds (View v){
        Connection conexion = null;
        String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.69;databaseName=Medicamentos;";
        String query = "Select Descripcion from Medicina where Nombre = '" + ConsulMed + "'";
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            Statement state = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultado = state.executeQuery(query);
            while (resultado.next()){
                String res = resultado.getString(1);
                TextView Explicacion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mltExplic);
                Explicacion.setText(res);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_farmaciapp);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your error log.

Comment: BTW, using jdbc is not recommended according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7221716/7557205)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: put that `Meds()` function's code in an **AsyncTask**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you are trying to access which haven't yet created. Or in another word we can't reference or call *findViewById* until the layout is inflated.

so make below changes

```
  public class Farmaciapp extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edtMed;
    String ConsulMed = edtMed.getText().toString();

    public void Meds (View v){
        Connection conexion = null;
        String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.69;databaseName=Medicamentos;";
        String query = "Select Descripcion from Medicina where Nombre = '" + ConsulMed + "'";
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            Statement state = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultado = state.executeQuery(query);
            while (resultado.next()){
                String res = resultado.getString(1);
                TextView Explicacion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mltExplic);
                Explicacion.setText(res);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_farmaciapp);
        edtMed =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtMedicamento);
    }
}
```

make sure to access edtMed after onCreate not before that will work. onCreate() is the way for activity to inflate the layout.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Do `findViewById` inside `onCreate()` method

Declare your `EditText edtMed` as global

```
 EditText edtMed;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_farmaciapp);

         edtMed =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtMedicamento);

    }
```

Also get text from your `EditText` inside `Meds (View v)`

```
public void Meds (View v){

         String ConsulMed = edtMed.getText().toString();
        Connection conexion = null;
        String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.69;databaseName=Medicamentos;";
        String query = "Select Descripcion from Medicina where Nombre = '" + ConsulMed + "'";
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            Statement state = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultado = state.executeQuery(query);
            while (resultado.next()){
                String res = resultado.getString(1);
                TextView Explicacion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mltExplic);
                Explicacion.setText(res);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```