# How to draw multiple charts on android Activity

Tags: android

I need to display multiple charts with in the Activity,refer the below image to represent the view what i need exactly.How can i get this view. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for drawing chart there so many library are available in market paid or free :: i give you link which help to you find chart

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android/772757#772757

from this i recommend `AChartEngine` it is free ware and build by apache

Comment: I know the Libraries available for drawing charts well,but i don't know how to use library to get the above attached image to draw multiple charts on single activity.

Comment: this all library provide a jar file in which class are exist. you need to download those jar file and import it in your current project, if you not aware that how to import external jar then   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project    will guide you

Comment: i know the way to import external jar with my project set up,here my need is to get four charts on single activity as like above attachment,don't know how to place the view with four charts

Comment: you need to R & d in it after import library

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK does not come with a graph drawing tool, so either you need to create one yourself or find a 3rd party library that can make it for you. Just google it.

If you want to know HOW to get multiple Views inside a View, you can put them inside a ScrollView, and you will be able to have them under each other.