# Android Google API Java Client com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-api-java-client

I was trying to do a simple app using the Google Tasks API. Something simple it's turning into a nightmare. Maybe it's something simple, probably it is, but I can't figure it out.

The problem: I was following the example of `TasksSample.java` from Google but I can't compile even after [importing the libraries and dependencies required](http://code.google.com/apis/tasks/articles/oauth-and-tasks-on-android.html). I'm using `Google API Java Client version 1.5.0`.

The problem it's when I access the GoogleAccessProtectedResource class. The import is:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessProtectedResource;
```

I always, and I mean always, no matter what code I have get the following error:

> 09-26 03:14:38.372: ERROR/dalvikvm(18731): Could not find class 'com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessProtectedResource', referenced from method com.greven.test.google.tasks.GoogleTasksTake100Activity.
>   09-26 03:14:38.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18731): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-26 03:14:38.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18731): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessProtectedResource

I really can't see where the problem is. I imported all the needed .jars... I guess

As you can see in this picture the class is obviously imported:

[image: ScreenShot]

So what other options do I have to fix this? Use Maven? I'm clueless now. I never thought I would have a problem like this. Oh I also tested on different computers, other Google java api client (version 1.4) and same thing happened. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as per your screenshot that your imported jar is imported in Eclipse, however for your Android application to work you need these jars to be dropped into a specific folder so that it is added to your APK and so the emulator and the Android devices find it.

It seems you should drop these jars in a folder named `/libs` at the root of your project. See this SO question: [How can I use external JARs in an Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project)

The Article you are referring too uses the `/assets` folder but this might have changed a few Android versions ago.