# Adding referenced jars to android build.xml

Tags: android, ant, classpath

I have an android eclipse project and have generated the corresponding build.xml ant file by doing:

```
android update test-project -p . -m ..\main_project
```

This compiles fine. However, in eclipse I have then added three referenced external jars (easymock, objenesis and cglib). In eclipse everything builds fine but then when I run the above command again it doesn't add these jars to the classpath.

So my question is how to tell the build.xml to include these jars?

I have done some research first and some people suggested changing the rules files in the sdk itself but this is something I want to avoid as then everyone in my team would need to do this and that's not practical.

Thanks
Stephen

Comment: You can add jars to java classpath for android using eclipse as follows
Right click on project > properties > Java Build path > Add External Jars.

Comment: Follow this :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project/6859020#6859020

Comment: Hi, I added them successfully to the eclipse project and there is no problem. What I need to get working is the ant build.xml files for automation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For build.xml you can set property  "external.libs.dir" in one of your properties file( like *build.properties*), by default it points to **libs/** folder of your project - simply put there all your jars

```
external.libs.dir=<your_custom_path>/lib
```

Comment: `external.libs.dir` does not work for newer version, use the taranfx answer instead

Comment: Yes, they extensively changing ant scripting to separate out libraries as standalone components

Comment: See @geeknizer answer below for SDK 13.

Answer (score 13):

add jar.libs.dir=your_path_here/lib in ant.properties for SDK >=8

Comment: ... or your_path_here/libs which is the default for SDK 13.  See the jar.libs.dir property in $SDK_DIR/tools/ant/build.xml.

Comment: is this mandatory to have a sub folder named lib/ or libs/ in my custom lib directory. Should the path be relative to the build.xml file at the root of my project, or absolute ?

Answer (score 1):

You should ideally use *libs/* not *lib*, to remain consistent with Eclipse.

Comment: Joe Malin is correct. libs/ is recommended by the android documentation. http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects