# Build.xml jar.libs.dir

Tags: android, ant

I have tried to figure out how to link library jars to my android project.

I created the build.xml with

```
android update project -p .
```

And I have defined **ant.properties** as

```
jar.libs.dir=lib
```

I also added a -pre-build task to copy some libs to the directory:

```
<target name="-pre-build">
  <copy todir="${jar.libs.dir}">
    <fileset 
      dir="absolute-path-from-my-dir" 
      includes="*.jar" />
  </copy>
</target>
```

and this succeeds, since I can see this in the ant output:

```
-pre-build:
     [copy] Copying 2 files to absolute-path-to-my-lib
```

However, I can also see this:

```
-build-setup:
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MyAndroidApp...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 2.3.3
[gettarget] API level:        10
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MyAndroidApp...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
```

and the javac task fails, since it cannot find classes that are in the libraries.

What am I missing?

Comment: Take a look at this previously asked question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723135/adding-referenced-jars-to-android-build-xml

Comment: I did already. And I defined jar.libs.dir accordingly in ant.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is the solution:

[Is jar.libs.dir not being overridden properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637852/is-jar-libs-dir-not-being-overridden-properly)

So it's a bug in Android:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33194