# How can I speed up the packaging of external jars into an apk in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an android project which has four external jar files in the libs folder. When I build the project, it takes 5 minutes to package these jar files into an apk.

These jar files were added as described in [How can I use external JARs in an Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project)

According to the Console, it appears that Dalvik is processing each file in the jar:

```
[2011-10-12 13:01:53 - MyProject] Dx processing org/some/file.class
```

I'm not going to change these libraries, so it seems like a waste of time and really slows down my development.

What's the best approach to dealing with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar symptoms.
Please make sure that eclipse.ini doesn't contains a similar line:

CompileThreshold=5

If it does, just remove any CompileThreshold specifications from your config.