# Integration of external jar file in android application using adt 20

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use external jar file in android application. The jar file is running well in another java application but when I am trying to use the Jar file with Android Application by BuildPath-> Add External Jars; it is showing following errors

"could not find class  referenced from method ".

Please help me out from this.

Thanks

Shorav

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use external JARs in an Android project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the ADK update has messed-up with your project's build-path. Try removing the JAR and add it again to your libs folder, and do a Clean Project.

following poster's comment about not having a libs folder:

You should try this:

Remove all references to the JAR in your project -> your code should not build without error anymore

Create à libs folder at the root of your project

Copy the JAR into the libs folder

(If still not running OK) Right click your project > Android Tools > Fix Project Propertie

Comment: I tried this but without success.

Following errors are coming up -

07-04 17:52:03.802: E/dalvikvm(223): Could not find class 'org.AstroVed.Panchanga.Moment', referenced from method com.astroved.horawatch.HoraWatchActivity.onCreate

Please explain your process once again because in ADT 20, libs folder are automatically created. I tried in both ways . By creating own libs folder and copying the jar file there as well as through importing external jar through Configure Build path.


Thanks

Comment: just copy jar file into the libs folder, no need to do more than that

Comment: Still the same error is coming .....I removed my own created libs folder and then copied the jar file in automatically generated libs folder of the project---> clean the project and then Run but without success. Please have you any other solutions??????

thanks   
Shorav

Comment: i solved this problem by using the above process when i was get. try to do step by step process you can get it..

Comment: Yes, I am trying to solve it as you said from start. Let me see. may i have your skype id...?

Comment: If I am running jar file on cmd through command or in Java application it is running well and i am getting desired result. So I suppose that Jar is correct and there is no error in Jar file. Is it a versioning of ADT problems or jar problems?? could you please clarify ????

Comment: i think ADT problem, i was also faced same problem when i was updated my andorid SDK.

Comment: yes.. i am also having the same conclusion but trying to get it run...thanks for your guidance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653619/include-jar-into-apk-with-eclipse
I have compiled the Jar file in Java 1.7 version. Is there any problems with this ???? I have gone through the above link where I found jar should be built on Java 1.6?????Please help???

Comment: i sent the request as well in SKYPE.

Comment: I posted the same question by copying LogCat. Please have a look for getting the correct ideas about the errors. I am just stuck with this. I tried same way as you said...the external jar is visible in Android dependecies as well as. but application is forced to close unexpectedely. Please help ...

Comment: nothing working ....i am just struggling with this...............

However the problem is at runtime not at compile time  because When I am importing the same class ... it is visible and I am able to intialize the constructor for the same class without error...but at run time it is showing following error--

Could not find class 'org.AstroVed.Panchanga.Moment', referenced from method com.astroved.horawatch.HoraWatchActivity.onCreate
07-06 10:32:07.244: W/dalvikvm(319): 
Is it  error related to class path??????

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a Jar in android application you may create it like this:

1. Open your IDE
2. Click on new
3. Choose new Android project
4. Give the name of your project
5. Check option make this project as library