# How to deploy an Android shared library

Tags: android, android-library

I've built a shared library named `com.example.multiplecontacts`. This library contains one activity named `MultipleContacts`. I'd like to use it in another application named `com.example.test`

I've added the following line to the Test Manifest

```
<uses-library android:name="com.example.multiplecontacts" android:required="true"/>
```

But the following error appears

```
Package com.example.test requires unavailable shared library com.example.multiplecontacts; failing!
```

I've checked Is Library checkbox in my library and added it as a reference to my application through Properties->Android->Add

What else should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Create a libs folder and put your library in there, then add that folder to the library path.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project)

Comment: This links explains how add a JAR file to an Android project. My shared library is not a JAR file. As far as I know, you can't export an Android code as a JAR file. Review the accepted answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645442/android-class-not-found-from-imported-jar-file

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry - I overlooked. But you can export Android code as jar, it's just an archive of classes. Could you try that?

Comment: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.test/com.example.multiplecontacts.MultipleContacts}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

I think it requires me to include all my activities, layouts, and resources used in my library to the application manifest file. Is there any better way?

Comment: Copy/paste your library to your src folder directly (*.java files), resources to you know where.

Comment: The same problem. I need to add all my activities and layouts to the manifest manually. I need to import the library as a blackbox

Answer (score 0):

Making this a separate answer so it doesn't get lost in the comments. But here's a more official description of how to create a shared library in Android:  https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/java-library.