# ActionbarSherlock not working

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am having problems getting start with the ActionBarSherlock. I downloaded the 4.1.0 version and followed the following tutorial for installing it.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GJ6yY1lNNY

The Problem I am facing is whenever I make a new project and add the library project of ActionbarSherlock to it. I get the following error.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Work\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.1.0-0-g9598f2b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-88fc341\library\bin\com_actionbarsherlock.jar'   myapp       Build path  Build Path Problem
```

Please anybody help me with it.

Comment: have you put the jar in libs folder and link that in Build path in using eclipse ?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know how to do that. This is how I have added the library project. Right CLick the new Project, Then Properties, then Android, then I added the library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the same problem: A .jar file is requested, but non-existing. Also, it is okay that the file doesn't exist, because we want to use a Android-Library Project and not an included jar-library.

The steps described by Aqif Hamid are perfectly fine, if the missing import (.jar or library project) would be the root of the problem. But i figured out that the reason for this error is  that you have to set both projects (AndroidBar Sherlock and your own Android project) to **Java Compliance Level 1.6**

To do so go into Project Properties => Java Compiler and set the level to 1.6
Of course, you have to install JDK 1.6 on your computer...

Hope this helps you too!

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that it works for me was selecting at Properties at Java Compiler Tab Compilance Level --> 1.7 (It was 1.6).
After that Android Tools, Fix Project Properties

Answer (score 1):

DO the followings:

- just like you have `bin`, `res` folders. right click on your project and
  add a folder named 'libs' (if libs folder is not already there).
- Then copy paste your `com_actionbarsherlock.jar` file in this `libs` folder.
- Right-click on your `com_actionbarsherlock.jar` file and click `Add to Build Path`.
- Now clean and build your project. You should be good to go.

**Edit:**

To add project as a library do this:

- Make sure you have your library project in your projects list and it
  is  open.
- Right click on your project in which you want to add your library
  project and select `Porperties`.
- Click `Android` in properties windows, now scroll down, you will see
  library section at the bottom. There press `Add` button.
- Now a window will open in which you will see list of library
  porjects. Select your required project and press `Ok`. Now that library
  project must be there with a green tick mark.
- Press `Apply` and `Ok` button.
- You should be good to go now.

regards,
Aqif Hamid

Comment: Well there is no Jar file. Although I have made the project a library project.

Comment: `com_actionbarsherlock.jar` looks like a jar file, that your project is complaining about. :)

Comment: Yes Its asking for the missing Jar file but there is no JAr file of com_actionbarsherlock.jar.

Comment: if you donot have `com_actionbarsherlock.jar` then what you trying to add to your project. 
Aqif

Comment: I want to add that project as a library. Because I have made it the library project.

Answer (score 1):

I am of the understanding that you cannot include ActionBarSherlock into your project by adding a jar to your lib directory (or just including the jar at all).  You will have to create an android project for ActionBarSherlock then link to it as a library:

1. Create ActionBarSherlock project in Eclipse
2. Right-click your project and go to Properties
3. Select `Android` in the left pane
4. Then in the right pane, towards the bottom you can `Add...` the ActionBarSherlock project you created in step 1.

If you are curious why the jar approach doesn't work, I give you [Jake's reply in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/actionbarsherlock/a9BZ-ugABDA)
 (although that's a month and a half old at this point).

Answer (score 0):

1 - create a libs folder (parallel to manifest) and put the jar in that

Your Project -> right click -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Jar -> 
yourjar.jar

This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eY_uqi_qIz0) might be useful in case you are having some issues.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/jar-for-android/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project

Answer (score 0):

Clean your actionbarsherlock project. It will generate the .jar file for you when it re-builds.

Comment: Hi Brad, Tried it Its not generating the .jar file.

Comment: Not generating, but also no errors in the actionbarsherlock project (it should appear in the bin folder)?
What happens if you try a normal build project immediately following the clean?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Android Tools option to Add compatible libraries fixed the problem for me.