# ANDROID: SEND MAIL with PreConfigured mail:From Address without using mail provider(Like GMAIL,YAHOO pre-installed in ANDROID DEVICE)

Tags: android, email

I am trying to use `RECOVER PASSWORD` button which requires `MAIL SENDING` to correspondent USERNAME. I would like to know the way if somehow I can send MAIL (In Background) without using `GMAIL`, `YAHOO`(Pre Installed EMAIL Provider Service) with my own address like `abc@abc.com` to every user of my application.

Any Help is most welcome!!

Comment: You'll need a mail service which can work with SMTP protocol server-side. PHP and such server-side languages are easy to configure and use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send e-mail in Android using the JavaMail API using Gmail authentication

**Steps to create a simple Project:**

MailSenderActivity.java

```
YOUR PACKAGE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MailSenderActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {   
                    GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("username@gmail.com", "password");
                    sender.sendMail("This is Subject",   
                            "This is Body",   
                            "user@gmail.com",   
                            "user@yahoo.com");   
                } catch (Exception e) {   
                    Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
                } 

            }
        });

    }
}
```

GmailSender.java

```
YOUR PACKAGE;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;   
import javax.activation.DataSource;   
import javax.mail.Message;   
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;   
import javax.mail.Session;   
import javax.mail.Transport;   
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;   
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;   
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;   
import java.io.IOException;   
import java.io.InputStream;   
import java.io.OutputStream;   
import java.security.Security;   
import java.util.Properties;   

public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {   
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
    private String user;   
    private String password;   
    private Session session;   

    static {   
        Security.addProvider(new com.provider.JSSEProvider());   
    }  

    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {   
        this.user = user;   
        this.password = password;   

        Properties props = new Properties();   
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
    }   

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
    }   

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
        try{
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
        message.setSubject(subject);   
        message.setDataHandler(handler);   
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
        else  
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
        Transport.send(message);   
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }   

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
        private byte[] data;   
        private String type;   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
        }   

        public void setType(String type) {   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public String getContentType() {   
            if (type == null)   
                return "application/octet-stream";   
            else  
                return type;   
        }   

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
        }   

        public String getName() {   
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
        }   

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
        }   
    }   
}
```

JSSE Provider

```
/*
 *  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 *  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 *  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 *  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 *  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 *  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 */

/**
 * @author Alexander Y. Kleymenov
 * @version $Revision$
 */


import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.Provider;

public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

    public JSSEProvider() {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            public Void run() {
                put("SSLContext.TLS",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ADD 3 jars found in the following link to your Android Project

- [mail.jar](http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/mail.jar)
- [activation.jar](http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/activation.jar)
- [additionnal.jar](http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/additionnal.jar)

[Click here - How to add External Jars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6859020/28557)

Run the project and check your recipient mail account for the mail.
Cheers!!

Hope this helps

And don't forget that you cannot do network operation from the any UI activity in android.
So follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299) if you have any network issue:

Jar files : https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/